# How to get radio buttons wrapped in <span>s with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a SharePoint site and I cannot change the HTML. What I am trying to do is to get which radio button is selected but they are wrapped in span's. If I go by title on the span and then .next() I get the next element after the span which is incorrect so how should I do this?

HTML:

```
<span dir="none"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Tasmania"><input id="ctl00_m_g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede_ctl00_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede$ctl00$ctl04$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl00" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede_ctl00_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00">Tasmania</label></span></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Greenland"><input id="ctl00_m_g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede_ctl00_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede$ctl00$ctl04$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl01" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede_ctl00_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01">Greenland</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
<td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Hawaii"><input id="ctl00_m_g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede_ctl00_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede$ctl00$ctl04$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl02" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_f1c8ac33_8a36_42be_8901_5201d5b9eede_ctl00_ctl04_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02">Hawaii</label></span></td>
</tr>
</table></span>
```

I am trying to not use the name of the radio button group as this can change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ms-RadioText > input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span > input:radio:checked')
```

This will select all `input` elements, which are `checked`, and are direct child of `span` elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/FUn4e/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the selected radio buttons:

```
 $(".ms-RadioText input:radio:checked")
```

Comment: Yes sorry in the hurry of writing it i forgot one thing! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.ms-RadioText input[type='radio']:checked").value('this one is selected');
```

Comment: This will select all inputs on the page, not the ones wrapped inside `span` elements.

Comment: @Shef: Edited. Mine at least gets only checked

Comment: @genesis - I think you need `.filter` and not `.find` if you're doing it that way.

Comment: Now it will select checkboxes also, not only radio buttons.

Comment: @Shef: I was in the middle of editing. and I think .find() is fine in this case

Comment: @genesis - `.find` searches through *descendants* so it will look for an `:checked` element *within* an input, so no, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this for example:

```
$("span.ms-RadioText input[type=radio]:checked") // returns list of all inputs that are children of spans.
```

Comment: This won't get all the selected input radio buttons.

Comment: Now it's close to @karim79's answer, omitting the direct child parameter. :)